# Finite Sets Proof on Domains

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

Just wanted some help with this little proof.:

Let X and Y be Finite Sets. Prove that |X^Y| = |X|^|Y|

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199078/proof-of-the-definition-of-cardinal-exponentiation

Answer (score 1):

$X^Y$ is the set of functions $Y \to X$. Given a particular $y$ in $Y$, how many options are there for its image in $X$? What if you consider two points $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $Y$; how many ways can they be mapped to things in $X$? What if you consider all points in $Y$?

Comment: So for any particular y in Y there are |X| options for its image in X? and one less option for each additional point? And all points in Y have just the one option? I'm not sure what assumptions I can make on 'jectivity

Comment: @user208628 No, for each additional point, you still have $|X|$ options. Functions are allowed to map different points of $Y$ to same points of $X$.

Comment: i tried this from the X perspective, $x_1$ (if $|Y|=4$ for example) has $2^4$ possibilities, but calculating $x_2$ number of possibilities is now dependent on $x_1$.